# Не отображает блок при условном операторе, переменная оказывается пуста

Tags: php, html, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста. Сделал сокращённую форму для примера. Не могу разобраться, почему условный оператор  не отображает блок. Точнее понятно, что $count пуста. Подскажите почему мне говорит, что там пусто? Как исправить?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<style>
    html,body { height: 100%; width: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; }
    form { margin: 0 auto;  }
    h1 { text-align: center; }
    input { display: block;  margin: 0 auto; margin-bottom: 15px; }
</style>

<body>

    <form action="#" method="post">

        <!-- Если нашлось вывести уведомление  -->

        <?php if(empty($count)) { ?> <p>переменная пуста</p> <?php } ?>

        <div class="auth">

            <h1>Регистрация</h1>
            <input type="text" name="login">
            <input type="text" name="password">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">

        </div>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Прилагаю php код. В конце файла echo $count отображает число, следовательно переменная не пуста. Но при попытке вывести блок пишет пустая переменная.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['login'])) { $login = $_POST['login']; }
if(isset($_POST['password'])) { $password = $_POST['password']; }

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'blog');

if (!$con)
{
    die('Ошибка' . mysql_error());
    // echo "Подключение прошло успешно";
}

$query = "SELECT id FROM `user` WHERE login = '$login'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$count = $row['id'];
echo $count;

//Тут вроде всё ОК в php, значение приходит

?>
```

Comment: PHP-код пропишите над HTML-кодом.

Comment: @Fr3z0n как Вы передаёте данные в html?

Comment: @Denis640Kb вопрос не понял. 
mysqli_connect и ниже код.

Comment: @Fr3z0n В html файле не видно, чтобы Вы в него передавали переменную. По-этому и интересуюсь, как именно Вы передаёте туда параметр? mysli_connect - это подключение к базе данных.

Comment: @Эдуард получилось. Спасибо. Это прототип большого кода, задам вопрос. Почему когда в большой программе вставляю PHP код перед HTML, то на странице всё исчезает?

Comment: @Denis640Kb <?php if(!empty($count)) { ?> <p>переменная  имеет значение</p> <?php } ?>

Comment: @Так данные не передаются из файла в файл. Данные передаются либо через форму, либо после подключения файла через `include` или `require`.

Comment: всем спасибо. Всё сделал